# How to add a Tab Bar to an existing view controller, without XIB

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm **trying to avoid using Interface Builder** as much as possible.

At the moment I have the view controller created via code and change views via code as well.

I now need one of the steps to **send the app into** a new view with **a tab bar**, that will allow me to change views as well.

Ideally, what I'd do is tell the current view controller to add a Tab Bar to the bottom, but I'm not sure if that's doable, so I might have to swap the UIViewController with a UITabBarController?

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,
Andre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have Xcode on hand so I will try to answer verbally.

Create a new `UITabBarController` and set your current view as the `root view`, then add as much tabs as you want, (each tab has its own view).

**UPDATE**
After init'ing the controller, define an array of views (order of adding is important). And call this on the tab bar controller

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a simple code to create a tab bar with two empty views, each has its own tab button.

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

firstView = [[FirstView alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"First" image:nil tag:1] autorelease];
[firstView setTabBarItem:item1];

secondView = [[SecondView alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sec" image:nil tag:1] autorelease];
[secondView setTabBarItem:item2];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstView,secondView,nil] animated:NO];

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Of course this code won't be useful as is, you will need to create the views manually, or create a nib file for each view and load it in `initWithNibName`

**UPDATE 3**
Check this [Stanford iPhone Course](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225), it's a free course from Stanford univ. the lecturers are Apple employees. Lecture 7 titled **Navigation & Tab Bar Controllers** will give you a good start on those components.

Comment: Thanks :) I've added it to the view, it's appearing, with a blank canvas and an empty bar at the bottom.
Now I'm trying to figure out how to tell the tab bar to show a specific view on the white canvas and how to add 4 buttons to the empty tab bar at the bottom.

Comment: I've added my specific view to the white canvas. I'm using: tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];        [tabBarController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController, nil]];         viewController.view = step3;     where "step3" is the view I wanted to show. Now I'm just trying to add the actual tab buttons and associate actions to change the views

Comment: right, I've got the buttons in. any idea how to get each button to call a function to change the view? :)

cheers

Comment: i added the buttons by using: UINavigationController *tab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];    pushing that into an array and then setting the tabBarController.viewControllers with that array. The thing is it's automatically adding a navigation bar on the top. Is it because I'm using the UINavigationController to create buttons for the Tab Bar? How can I manipulate this nav bar? Using "tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBar" doesn't work :(

Comment: found that one, finally. now just need to link buttons to actions :) any thoughts?

Comment: still don't know how to track the Tab change, but thanks for the rest :D

Comment: I'm not sure i can help further, it should work right away, anyway, check the last update, i added a link to a lecture that might help