# How can I add the Three20 photo gallery to my tab bar iphone application?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, three20, photo-gallery

I am using an Tabbar based iPhone application, where I would like to implement a photo gallery with Three20. After hours of trying I was able to get this tutorial working (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-photo-gallery-three20/), everything just works fine.

Now I want to add this photo gallery to my tab bar based application. I have been searching the whole internet but I did not come up with a solution. My tabbar application is built up in Interface Builder. The whole Three20 stuff is not based on Interface Builder. I am not sure how to add this gallery to my tabbar. Yes, I have checked the built in example "TTNavigationDemo" --> the problem is that they are not using the Interface Builder at all and I need to mix it up somehow.

No navigation controller or anything like this is additionally needed. Does anyone have some code for me to help me fix this? I really appreciate your help, thanks guys!

cheers, 
dooonot

Comment: If not Three20, then what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to first create your tab bar controller programmatically, then port TTPhotoViewController to one of your tab bar items. Here is a great post on this topic: [How to add a Tab Bar to an existing view controller, without XIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492621/how-to-add-a-tab-bar-to-an-existing-view-controller-without-xib)

And then feel free to port other nib-based view controllers to the rest of your tab bar items.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but I think it must be possible to add this photo gallery to the tabbar, without having to change my complete tab bar project? This would be an overkill :(

Comment: I doubt it. At least I tried but failed. As a result in my project I re-wrote the structure underneath. It is actually not as time-comsuming as it looks. So I encourage you to give it a shot. :-)

Comment: One last question. I have found this tutorial (http://knol.google.com/k/iphone-sdk-tabbars#) which explains how to set up a tabbar app programmatically. Do you know if the different ViewControllers can use my current nib files? Or do I also need to change this? (You just said "Feel free to port other nib-based view controllers to the reost of your tab bar items").

Comment: My answer would be yes. Even though the tab bar is created programmatically, some of its children view controllers can be initialized with nib files (e.g. initWithNibName:@"YourNibName")

Comment: This is the same issue I'm looking at -- when you say "port TTPhotoViewController to one of your tab items" can you elaborate on how this is done exactly?